# time period in time period (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, time, intervals

i try to find out if a Timeperiod is inside a timeperiod. I have my reference time period and my comparative time period.
Let me make an example:

- Time period A (reference) goes from 1.1.2014 to 1.2.2014 (tt.mm.yyyy).
- Time period B (comparative) goes from 1.4.2014 to 1.5.2014.

=> This would be totaly ok.

- Time period C (reference) goes from 1.1.2014 to 1.3.2014
- Time period D (comparative) goes from 1.2.2014 to 1.5.2014.

=> Not ok because D is in C.

I hope you get what i want. I tried to make serval < = > if actions but this starts to get to huge and slow. Maybe there is a faster ways to do so.

Also, is MySQL able to do such things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this with `php timestamp`

```
$reference_start_date = "1.1.2014";
$reference_end_date = "1.2.2014";

$comparative_start_date = "1.4.2014";
$comparative_end_date = "1.5.2014 ";

$reference_start_time = strtotime(str_replace(".", "-", $reference_start_date);
$reference_end_time = strtotime(str_replace(".", "-", $reference_end_date);

$comparative_start_time = strtotime(str_replace(".", "-", $comparative_start_date);
$comparative_end_time = strtotime(str_replace(".", "-", $comparative_end_date);

if($comparative_start_time>$reference_start_time && $comparative_start_time<$reference_end_time)
{
    echo "Not OK";
}
else if($comparative_end_time>$reference_start_time && $comparative_end_time<$reference_end_time)
{
    echo "Not OK";
}
else if($comparative_start_time<$reference_start_time && $comparative_end_time>$reference_end_time)
{
     echo "Not OK";
}
else
{
     echo "OK";
}
```

Comment: Tried this and seems to work well. Better than my if-else-mess. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can do like below:

Check `Reference_start >= comparative_start && Reference_end < comparative_end`, If this condition become true than your time will be overlapped.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `reference` period (having `startDate` and `endDate`) and you have a `comparative` period, then you can have this `where` clause in MySQL:

```
where ((reference.startDate > comparative.endDate) or reference.endDate < comparative.startDate)
```

which would be true if the two periods have no intersection.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your dates give in UTC it is really simple to compare two date ranges. There are 5 specific cases that could happen:

```
11111......
......22222

..11111.....
.....22222..

...11111....
...22222....

.....11111..
..22222.....

......11111
22222......
```

Only the first and the last one are the ones you are looking for. It's easy to construct an if query of it and negate it:

```
if (!($dateRange1End <= $dateRangeStart2 && $dateRange2End <= $dateRange1Start))
    // NOT OKAY
else
    // OKAY
```